# HMAC SHA256 in Swift 4

Tags: swift, cryptography, swift4, hmac, cryptoswift

I have a string and a key, which i want to generate an HMAC SHA256 from it. Although i'm using 2 libs

[IDZSwiftCommonCrypto](https://github.com/iosdevzone/IDZSwiftCommonCrypto) and [CryptoSwift](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#hmac-based-key-derivation-function)

and [this answer](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift#hmac-based-key-derivation-function)

Nothing really worked for me. My source of truth are those 2 websites

https://myeasywww.appspot.com/utility/free/online/Crypt_Decrypt-MD5-AES-HMAC-SHA-DES-RABBIT/en?command=UTILITY&ID=2

and

https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output

Which they always generate the correct hash key for my case.
Any idea in what can work here? Some code samples

For IDZSwiftCommonCrypto

```
func getHMacSHA256(forMessage message: String, key: String) -> String? {
    let hMacVal = HMAC(algorithm: HMAC.Algorithm.sha256, key: key).update(string: message)?.final()
    if let encryptedData = hMacVal {
        let decData = NSData(bytes: encryptedData, length: Int(encryptedData.count))
        let base64String = decData.base64EncodedString(options: .lineLength64Characters)
        print("base64String: \(base64String)")
        return base64String
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

And for CryptoSwift

```
    let password: Array<UInt8> = Array(payload.utf8)
    let salt: Array<UInt8> = Array("somekey".utf8)

    let signedBody = try? HKDF(password: password, salt: salt, variant: .sha256).calculate()
```

But nothing really works like the sources of truth.Any idea?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've been using this:

```
import Foundation

enum CryptoAlgorithm {
    case MD5, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512

    var HMACAlgorithm: CCHmacAlgorithm {
        var result: Int = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:      result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
        case .SHA1:     result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
        case .SHA224:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
        case .SHA256:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
        case .SHA384:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
        case .SHA512:   result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
        }
        return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
    }

    var digestLength: Int {
        var result: Int32 = 0
        switch self {
        case .MD5:      result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA1:     result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA224:   result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA256:   result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA384:   result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
        case .SHA512:   result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
        }
        return Int(result)
    }
}

extension String {

    func hmac(algorithm: CryptoAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
        let str = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let strLen = Int(self.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
        let digestLen = algorithm.digestLength
        let result = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: digestLen)
        let keyStr = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
        let keyLen = Int(key.lengthOfBytes(using: String.Encoding.utf8))

        CCHmac(algorithm.HMACAlgorithm, keyStr!, keyLen, str!, strLen, result)

        let digest = stringFromResult(result: result, length: digestLen)

        result.deallocate(capacity: digestLen)

        return digest
    }

    private func stringFromResult(result: UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>, length: Int) -> String {
        let hash = NSMutableString()
        for i in 0..<length {
            hash.appendFormat("%02x", result[i])
        }
        return String(hash).lowercased()
    }
}
```

You'll need to add `#import <CommonCrypto/CommonHMAC.h>` to your Objective-C bridging header.

Source: [@thevalyreangroup on this github thread](https://gist.github.com/thewheat/7342c76ade46e7322c3e#gistcomment-1769792)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This approach gives me the same result as my source of truth :D

Comment: Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10) finally provides CommonCrypto! Just add `import CommonCrypto` in your swift file.

Comment: @Christina - I've referenced your solution on another question here, I would love some insight as I am getting different values for the hmac produced here and one produced in .net https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625832/hmac-sha256-in-c-sharp-vs-hmac-sha256-in-swift-dont-match

Comment: The unnecessary use of extensions in this solution makes it much more confusing than it needs to be imho.

Answer (score 39):

### If you target iOS 13.0+ or macOS 10.15+, use Apple's CryptoKit

```swift
import CryptoKit

let secretString = "my-secret"
let key = SymmetricKey(data: Data(secretString.utf8))

let string = "An apple a day keeps anyone away, if you throw it hard enough"

let signature = HMAC<SHA256>.authenticationCode(for: Data(string.utf8), using: key)
print(Data(signature).map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()) // 1c161b971ab68e7acdb0b45cca7ae92d574613b77fca4bc7d5c4effab89dab67
```

Answer (score 9):

You're doing it wrong with CryptoSwift.

For future readers, here's how to do it:

```swift
let result = try! HMAC(key: key, variant: .sha256).authenticate(message.bytes)
```

Comment: This works exactly as it should with CryptoSwift library. 

Answer (score 3):

## Swift 4.2 solution for **HMAC** encryption

Not so long ago I had the same problem, so I wrote simple framework for use in Swift on all platforms - **iOS** **macOS** and **tvOS**

It's called ***EasyCrypt*** and you can find it here:
https://github.com/lukszar/EasyCrypt

This framework let you encrypt message with your key, using HMAC algorithms.
Usage is simple, like following:

```
let crypto = EasyCrypt(secret: "mySecretKey", algorithm: .sha256)
let result = crypto.hash("This is very secret text to encrypt")
let otherResult = crypto.hash("This is another secret text to encrypt")

print("result: ", result)
print("otherResult: ", otherResult)
```

You can fast install using Carthage. Inside project you can find Playground for demo usage with instructions.

Comment: I get: Could not find module 'EasyCrypt' for architecture 'armv7'; found: arm64, x86_64

Comment: @user2983041 what platform do you want to use it with?

Comment: xCode is running in newest mac mini in market (i3 3.60 ghz). App test run in real device (iPhone 5)

Comment: This accepted answer did not work for me, for some reason it returns a different value from what I expect. EasyCrypt did work for me. Thanks.