# How to create a HMAC MD5 Hex signature using SWIFT 4?

Tags: ios, swift, cryptography, md5, hmac

I'm trying to create a HMAC MD5 Hex signature using SWIFT 4.

We'll use a sample string -> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec non metus erat. Nam nec dolor ut neque suscipit viverra in sit amet odio. Cras eleifend sed risus eget luctus"

a sample key -> `"6fa9b1de89d0707f6dc952349166bbe7"`

The result in my code is `"dd2cef2b06ddb08e16c32a4ddc583d11"`

The result on most websites is `"dd2cef2b06ddb08e16c32a4ddc583d11"`

The result on Cryptii.com is `"7eda9d3c1356402e6fce39af3bc8d195"`

The payment handler uses the exact signature from Cryptii.com as reference and I cannot generate it in iOS, using swift 4.
I used the CryptoSwift library and others(https://gist.github.com/MihaelIsaev/f913d84b918d2b2c067d, [Implementing HMAC and SHA1 encryption in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26970807/implementing-hmac-and-sha1-encryption-in-swift)).

I use this code (from CryptoSwift):

```
let keyArr: Array<UInt8> = Array(key.utf8) 
let stringArr: Array<UInt8> = Array(string.utf8) 
do { 
let a = HMAC.init(key: keyArr, variant: .md5) 
let encrypted3 = try a.authenticate(stringArr) 
print("Encrypted string: (encrypted3.toHexString())") 
} catch { }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

The android implementation looks like this and it works:

```
private String getFpHash(String source, String secretKey) {
    try {
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5");
        byte[] hexKeyBytes = HexEncoder.toBytesFromHex(secretKey);
        mac.init(new SecretKeySpec(hexKeyBytes, "HmacMD5"));
        String hexEncoded = HexEncoder.toHexFromBytes(mac.doFinal(source.getBytes()));
        return hexEncoded;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public class HexEncoder
{
   public static final String[] HEX_TABLE = new String[]{
            "00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "0a", "0b", "0c", "0d", "0e", "0f",
            "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "1a", "1b", "1c", "1d", "1e", "1f",
            "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "2a", "2b", "2c", "2d", "2e", "2f",
            "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "3a", "3b", "3c", "3d", "3e", "3f",
            "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "4a", "4b", "4c", "4d", "4e", "4f",
            "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "5a", "5b", "5c", "5d", "5e", "5f",
            "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "6a", "6b", "6c", "6d", "6e", "6f",
            "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "7a", "7b", "7c", "7d", "7e", "7f",
            "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "8a", "8b", "8c", "8d", "8e", "8f",
            "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "9a", "9b", "9c", "9d", "9e", "9f",
            "a0", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ae", "af",
            "b0", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "be", "bf",
            "c0", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "ca", "cb", "cc", "cd", "ce", "cf",
            "d0", "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5", "d6", "d7", "d8", "d9", "da", "db", "dc", "dd", "de", "df",
            "e0", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "e6", "e7", "e8", "e9", "ea", "eb", "ec", "ed", "ee", "ef",
            "f0", "f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5", "f6", "f7", "f8", "f9", "fa", "fb", "fc", "fd", "fe", "ff",
    };

    public static byte[] toBytesFromHex(String hex) {
        byte rc[] = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < rc.length; i++) {
            String h = hex.substring(i * 2, i * 2 + 2);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(h, 16);
            rc[i] = (byte) x;
        }
        return rc;
    }

    public static String toHexFromBytes(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer rc = new StringBuffer(bytes.length * 2);
        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            rc.append(HEX_TABLE[0xFF & bytes[i]]);
        }
        return rc.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have already implemented this in Swift, post the Swift. You almost certainly are encoding something incorrectly. When you say "most websites," which specific sites do you mean?

Comment: Do you really need that hex string table?  I can't believe you do.

Comment: Sight unseen, I bet you're decoding `7eda9d3c1356402e6fce39af3bc8d195` as either UTF-8 or base64 rather than hex. Looking at Cryptii, I strongly suspect it is correct.

Comment: Confirmed; you're decoding the key as UTF-8 rather than Hex. That's what leads to your incorrect "dd 2c ef 2b 06 dd b0 8e 16 c3 2a 4d dc 58 3d 11".

Comment: it's nearly always encoding issues when hash/hmac is wrong. Also endianness but that's much less likely

Comment: I use this code: let keyArr: Array<UInt8> = Array(key.utf8)
        let stringArr: Array<UInt8> = Array(string.utf8)
        do {
            let a = HMAC.init(key: keyArr, variant: .md5)
            let encrypted3 = try a.authenticate(stringArr)
            print("Encrypted string: \(encrypted3.toHexString())")
         } catch { }

Comment: And I also used the solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52784823/hmac-sha256-in-swift-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the shoulders of giants etc., using this extension to split your key string up into pairs of characters:

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/34454633/325366
extension Collection {
    var pairs: [SubSequence] {
        var startIndex = self.startIndex
        let count = self.count
        let n = count/2 + count % 2
        return (0..<n).map { _ in
            let endIndex = index(startIndex, offsetBy: 2, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { startIndex = endIndex }
            return self[startIndex..<endIndex]
        }
    }
}
```

... we can turn your key `String` into a `[UInt8]`:

```
let keyBytes = key.pairs.map { byteStr -> UInt8 in
    var value: UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: String(byteStr)).scanHexInt32(&value)
    return UInt8(clamping: value)
}
```

... and anticipating a desire to print the final hex value out we can write an extension on `Array`:

```
extension Array where Element == UInt8 {
    var asHexString: String {
        return self.map { String(format: "%0x", $0) }
                   .joined()
    }
}
```

... which results in your original code:

```
let stringArr: Array<UInt8> = Array(string.utf8)
do {
    let authenticator = HMAC(key: keyBytes, variant: .md5)
    let hmac = try authenticator.authenticate(stringArr)

    print("Message HMAC: \(hmac.asHexString)")
} catch { }
```

... printing out the value you are looking for:

```
Encrypted string: 7eda9d3c1356402e6fce39af3bc8d195
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This response solved my problem

Comment: @Emilia I've edited the final code block slightly to call the HMAC initialiser without the unnecessary `.init(...)` and changed some variable names to better reflect their meaning. The final result isn't an encrypted version of the message string (it isn't reversible), it's more like a signature or a fingerprint.