# Connecting to Apple - Device Check Api

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to check if my app was ever installed on a device using Device Check Api by apple. But it always returns error 400: Missing or incorrectly formatted payload

**NOTE: I have already checked existing stackoverflow questions like:**

[Connecting to Apple Store Connect using Swift (with SwiftJWT) and REST API's - failing with 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68319568/connecting-to-apple-store-connect-using-swift-with-swiftjwt-and-rest-apis-f)

[How do I generate a JWT to use in API authentication for Swift app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60290703/how-do-i-generate-a-jwt-to-use-in-api-authentication-for-swift-app)

None of them helped my resolving the issue.

Instead of server side implementation, we are trying to fetch this information from swift code itself.

Below is the code to create a JWT token using SwiftJWT.

```
func generateJWT() -> String? {
    let myHeader = Header(kid: "*********")
    let myClaims = MyClaims(iss: "*******", iat: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
    
    var myJWT = JWT(header: myHeader, claims: myClaims)
    
    guard let privateKeyPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AuthKey", withExtension: ".p8") else { return nil }
    
    do {
        let privateKey: Data = try Data(contentsOf: privateKeyPath, options: .alwaysMapped)
        let jwtSigner = JWTSigner.es256(privateKey: privateKey)
        let signedJWT = try myJWT.sign(using: jwtSigner)
        return signedJWT
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

To Fetch Device Token and call apple's Device check api:

```
private func generateIdentifier(completion: @escaping (_ token: String) -> Void) {
    let device = DCDevice.current
    if device.isSupported {
        device.generateToken { data, error in
            if let token = data?.base64EncodedString() {
                completion(token)
            }
        }
    }
}

func queryDeviceInfo() {
    guard let jwtToken = generateJWT() else { return }
    generateIdentifier { token in
        let router = ServiceRouter<ReferralApi>()
        router.alamofireRequest(.queryBits(deviceToken: token,
                                           jwtToken: jwtToken)) { [weak self] (response) in
            
            
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what's inside .queryBits(deviceToken: token, jwtToken: jwtToken)

```
 var url: String {
    switch self {
    case .queryBits:
        return "https://api.development.devicecheck.apple.com/v1/query_two_bits"
        default:
            return "\(baseURL)\(path)"
    }
}

var headers: HTTPHeaders? {
    switch self {
    case .queryBits(_, let jwt):
        let dic: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Authorization" : "Bearer \(jwt)"
        ]
        return dic
    }
}
var parameters: [String: Any]? {
    switch self {
    case .queryBits(let deviceToken, _):
        return [
            "device_token": deviceToken,
            "timestamp": Date().timeIntervalSince1970*1000,
            "transaction_id": UUID().uuidString]
    default:
            return nil
    }
}
```

Any help would be more than appreciated.

**EDIT** Here is the screenshot of the request payload:

[image]

Comment: There is no point to device check if you aren’t filtering through a server if someone wants to bypass they will just intercept the check

Comment: @loremipsum We will be using server side for this implementation later on. It's just a temporary solution at mobile end meanwhile the server gets ready. Our server side is also facing this same issue due to which we thought of trying at frontend.

Comment: Does `router.alamofireRequest` POST the data in JSON format? The response of 400 suggests that it doesn't. Can you capture the payload that you are sending?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, the data is in JSON format. I am attaching the screenshot for it.

Comment: The error message is right there in your screen shot!  The `timestamp` has a decimal component. Remove that. You must send an integer.

Comment: @Paulw11 That was one of the reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure out the issue. My request had the below issues:

- Missing JSON Encoding
- Invalid TimeStamp Formatting

**Missing JSON Encoding:** Since I was using Alamofire for making a request, setting Content-Type to application/json was not enough, I had to change encoding to JSON Encoding. This is basically the major reason for error 400.

**Invalid TimeStamp Formatting:** This is kind os tricky. Since timestamp is needed in two places. Both accept different formats.

**Place 1:** When you are trying to pass timestamp in the payload for the header, the **iat** key should be having timestamp in seconds as an integer value.

```
let myClaims = MyClaims(iss: "7X56L99KA2", iat: Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970))
```

**Place 2:** When you are trying to pass timestamp in httpbody as request payload, timestamp should be in milli seconds and in integer value.

```
let postDict : [String: Any] = [
        "device_token": token,
        "timestamp": Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970)*1000,
        "transaction_id": UUID().uuidString]
```

Just because of the timestamp, you could get error 401, that could either be invalid timestamp, invalid payload or unable to verify token.